# Segmentation falut (core dump) when setting values for a QtableWidget in Pyside

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdb, pyside

i'm been having this particular problem with my Qtablewidget when i try to set the items in the table, i also notice that the error doesn't occur when i don't set the values but as soon as i add the code to set the values in the table i get the error, the strange thing is that at first when i click on the button that sets the table items and their values and later shows the window, it open's fine but when i close the window and attempt to open it again the application crashes i'm suspecting this behavior is because of some widgets that are not deleted properly but i don't know for sure here is the output i got from the back-trace of the core dump file with gdb

```
#0  0x0000000000000041 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fd8013972cf in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#2  0x00007fd8013973ec in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#3  0x00007fd8013974e9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#4  0x00007fd8035dc168 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x00007fd800e82d47 in QWidget::~QWidget() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#6  0x00007fd801f5f7d1 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PySide/QtGui.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#7  0x00007fd8035dc168 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#8  0x00007fd800e82d47 in QWidget::~QWidget() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#9  0x00007fd802067331 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PySide/QtGui.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#10 0x00007fd8035dc168 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#11 0x00007fd800e82d47 in QWidget::~QWidget() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#12 0x00007fd801d8efd1 in ?? ()
```

and here is the code i believe is faulty

```
            activity_level = [i.level for i in self.all_objects]
            for row, activity in enumerate(activity_level):
                activity = self.format_est_and_lst(activity)
                while len(activity[0]) < self.project_duration:
                    activity[0].append('0')
                for column, value in enumerate(activity[0]):
                    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    self.resourcelevel.level_ui.estTable.setItem(row, column, item)

            for column, value in enumerate(self.result[0]):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                row = len(activity_level)
                self.resourcelevel.level_ui.estTable.setItem(row, column, item)



            for row, activity in enumerate(activity_level):
                while len(activity[1]) < self.project_duration:
                    activity[1].append('0')
                for column, value in enumerate(activity[1]):
                    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    self.resourcelevel.level_ui.lstTable.setItem(row, column, item)

            for column, value in enumerate(self.result[1]):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                row = len(activity_level)
                self.resourcelevel.level_ui.lstTable.setItem(row, column, item)


            self.resourcelevel.show()
```

i also want to ask, what is the proper way of debugging a segfault to get the exact error apart from gdb, because gdb doesn't point out a specific line of widget that causes the segfault error and also is that the proper way of setting items in a table?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get better information from the segfault is to use a DEBUG build of PySide and likely Qt too.  This is possible (obviously) but, in my limited experience, difficult: you'll have to build both from source.

In the absence of that, your best option is to strip down your failing code to a much smaller and simpler example that still fails.  Get it down to 100 lines or so. At that point you'll probably have found what's wrong yourself. But, if you haven't, it will be small enough to post on Stack Overflow, as three_pineapples requested.

In this case, the problem is likely happening when the Qt code calls back on a Python object that has been deleted.  Possibly, for example, `QTableWidgetItem.data`.  This could happen when the Qt model of the table has got out of sync with the Python version - for example having the wrong number of rows.  This implies that the problem is quite likely not with the code immediately triggering the segfault (that you have posted) but instead earlier as the table is being set up and changed.